# Opening appearance settings changes icon scheme back to default Yaru

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-tweaks

Ubuntu 22.04

So I installed Papyrus icons through the terminal and set them as the icons through Tweaks.
[image: (tweaks config)]

After I open the Appearance section in settings, the icons change back to normal. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 has the new feature that you can change accent colors. As a very nice tweak, changing the accent color also adapts colors in the icons. That only works with Yaru, so the Appearance panel - unfortunatelly - has been programmed to require the icon set Yaru: it resets the icons to Yaru when you switch to it.

You can file an issue to the developers about this behavior. For now, your only option is to avoid the appearance panel.

- Avoid the Appearance panel, and if accidentally you open it, change your icons back. If you are bored by using tweaks each time to change your icons back, you can do quickly with a command, e.g. `gsettings set /org/gnome/desktop/interface/icon-theme 'Humanity-Dark'`.
- Perhaps a better option: remove the Appearance panel altogether. To do that, copy the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-ubuntu-panel.desktop` to your private `~/.local/share/applications` and add the line `Hidden=true` to the copied file. That way, you never will open it accidentally again.